# SQL Inner Join troubles - SQL71508 Error. Trying to innner join two tables

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

I wanted to test access on a table `Items` through a view that would implement multi-tenant operation where the code is currently single tenant.

So I renamed `Items` to `_Items` and set about to create a view called Items. If I do a simple

```
SELECT * FROM _Items
```

it works and the code is none the wiser. I then tried to join the items table with the users table so I could test multi-tenant access though the view, but am getting an error that I just don't understand.

Here is the query:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Items] 
AS 
    SELECT * 
    FROM _Items I 
    INNER JOIN Users U ON I.TenantId = U.TenantId
    WHERE U.UserName = SUSER_SNAME()
```

The asterisk in `SELECT * FROM` is flagged and hovering over it produces:

> SQL71508 :: The model already has an element that has the same name dbo.Items.Id.

Clicking update in VS2017 produces the same error for each column.

> SQL71508 :: The model already has an element that has the same name dbo.Items.Id.
>
> SQL71508 :: The model already has an element that has the same name dbo.Items.Id.
>
> SQL71508 :: The model already has an element that has the same name dbo.Items.Active.
>
> SQL71508 :: The model already has an element that has the same name dbo.Items.TenantId.
>
> SQL71508 :: The model already has an element that has the same name dbo.Items.Active.
>
> SQL71508 :: The model already has an element that has the same name dbo.Items.TenantId.

What am I doing wrong?

TIA

Comment: The issue is most probably your `select *` and you have the same column names in both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want your view to have the columns from _Items, filtered by Users, try

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW [dbo].[Items] AS 
SELECT I.* FROM _Items I INNER JOIN Users U
    ON I.TenantId = U.TenantId
WHERE U.UserName = SUSER_SNAME()
```

Your SQL would grab all columns from both Users and _Items, and you definitely have at least one column with the same name between them, that being TennantId, the column you're joining on.

Comment: Thanks Eric, That fixed it. I had tried _Items.* and Items.* just grasping at straws to no avail. How weird it looks that I is used before it is seemingly declared but such is SQL and I'm pretty lame at it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `VIEW` you're trying to create already exists. Use `CREATE OR ALTER VIEW` instead of `CREATE VIEW` to overwrite it.

Comment: In SQL Server it's `create or alter`